# "How to resolve the 'server error' in Solr 7"

Tags: solr, solr7

I want to install solr in my windows 10. but I am having this error 
I even have jdk version  1.8.0_112 and my solr version is solr_7.7.2.

I have followed each and ever step provided on website

`ERROR: Solr server directory E:\\server not found`

Comment: There seems to be a path missing here - how are you trying to start Solr?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/solr-control-script-reference.html):

> **`-d <dir>`:** Define a server directory, defaults to `server` (as in, `$SOLR_HOME/server`). It is uncommon to override this option. When running multiple instances of Solr on the same host, it is more common to use the same server directory for each instance and use a unique Solr home directory using the `-s` option. Example: `bin/solr start -d newServerDir`
>
> **`-s <dir>`:** Sets the `solr.solr.home` system property; Solr will create core directories under this directory. This allows you to run multiple Solr instances on the same host while reusing the same server directory set using the `-d` parameter. If set, the specified directory should contain a `solr.xml` file, unless `solr.xml` exists in ZooKeeper. The default value is `server/solr`. This parameter is ignored when running examples (`-e`), as the `solr.solr.home` depends on which example is run. Example: `bin/solr start -s newHome`

Is it possible that your Solr instance wants to use a specific home or server directory that just doesn't exist?